# Post pictures and tagged friends to facebook through ios app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sdk-3.0, social-framework

I find it disturbing that its very easy to pick friends with friendPicker (FacebookSDK) and post pictures is extremely easy with IOS 6.0 social framework but to post the two combined seems very difficult.

I'm looking into the Facebook Open Graph API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/

It seems very difficult in comparison since it requires application server etc. Its however the only solution I have found so far.

Is the use of the Open Graph API the way to go, to post a picture with tagged friends to facebook wall, or is there anything in the IOS Social Framework that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Facebook Object API, you no longer need to set up a server in order to host Open Graph objects. You can directly create/add them to Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/

You can also use the native Share Dialog (in versions 3.5+ of the SDK) to share Open Graph stories with photos and user tagging embedded. See the Scrumptious app on how to create a story with photos and tags and publishing either via Open Graph directly, or using the native Share Dialog.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is scrumptious using shared dialog? It says that shared dialog cant run in simulator on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialog/ but the scrumptious app seems to work fine in simulator. I just dont understand the SCOGMealAction it is using.

Comment: Step 2 in scrumptious is called, set up back-end server:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/#step2

Comment: Those docs are for the initial version of Scrumptious, before the object API was released. If you try the Scrumptious app, and use "skip login" on the initial splash page, it will use the share dialog and the object API.

Comment: Ok, sweet! I look into that. I'm trying to use the most basic openSharedDialog code example I Could find but nothing happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527976/open-graph-action

Comment: And I still dont understad why it says that you cant runt the Shared Dialog in the facebook docs when you say that Scroumptios is using the Shared Dialog.